# Аналог sliding-menu для html

Tags: mobile-web, html, ui, javascript

Подскажите аналог [этой штуки](http://youtu.be/8vNaANLHw-c?t=46s) для сайтов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[вот](http://www.rudebox.org.ua/amazing-slider-content-jquery/) собственно. на место фоток просто ставим контент.

Comment: совсем не то, посмотрите видео